# Maintain Single instance of an activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

i have button in my first activity called Start.

Now when i click on this button it takes 1 to 2 seconds to load the next activity, now at that time the user clicks on the start button multiple times so what happens is that the next activity will open multiple times.

How to overcome this? Is there any way that even if the user clicks on the Start button multiple times open the activity only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Options:

- On click, disable the button and display a `ProgressDialog` to the user.
- Use the `Intent` flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to ensure only one activity is maintained on the stack. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
- Use the qualifer `launchMode=singleInstance` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` so only one instance of your `Activity` is allowed at a time. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

I would recommend the first, because it can show the user your application is still working even if it takes a few seconds to do the necessary processing to begin your `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the launch mode of your 2nd activity as "Single Instance" in your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use anything like a `launchMode` or `Intent flags`. They are used for different purposes.

Description [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

What you have to do is:

1. Show a progress dialog to clearly show the user that an
   action(calling 2nd Activity) is in progress. This was user will not
   try to click the button multiple times
2. Simply disable the button's click listener after 1st click. This is not
   recommended because user might not be able to know whether he/she
   clicked the button. Also this is the case where user tends to click
   the button multiple times.